# Is there a function to add and calculate the times in this query?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datediff

I have a table with a [ID] ,[Timestamp] and [Message].

The [Timestamp] is in '2021-03-31 22:37:09.580' format and I want to calculate the time it takes for an advisor to answer the webchat conversion.
So far I have the following

I want to add the [Timestamp] to either of those messages and then calculate the difference between each one.

The current query returns the following

[image: Outcome]

Can anyone help?

```
select
    [message] 
    ,NextMessage
from (
    select id 
            , [message]
           ,lead([message]) over (order by id) as NextMessage
    from bot.ConversationsResolved
) as t
where [message] = ('You''re being connected to the next available advisor.')
```

Comment: What's wrong with `DATEDIFF`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it

Comment: *"The [Timestamp] is in '2021-03-31 22:37:09.580' format"* Date and time data types don't have a "format", they are binary values. If your column `timestamp` really is stored in a "format", then it by definition isn't a date and time data type but a string based data type (`varchar`/`nvarchar`); that is a significant design flaw you will need to fix.

Comment: *"I'm not sure how to use it "* Did you check the documentation on it? It has plenty of examples. What about the documentation, and examples it includes, didn't you understand? Show us your attempt with `DATEDIFF` so we can explain where you went wrong.

Comment: It's data type is datetime

Comment: _I want to add_ OK - so do that. Update your code and the query result. You need to calculate the difference, so why do you think you only need to add it to "either". You need to add it to all of them to order to calculate a **difference**.

Comment: If I knew how to mate I would have done, that's why i'm on here asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

As some other users have rather 'helpfully' mentioned, you can find the syntax of the `datediff` function within Microsoft's documentation for SQL Server here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

From this you can see that you need to specify a `datepart` which is the unit of time you want to measure as well as the start and end dates that you want to measure between.  You use this in your `select` statement and it returns the value in a new column:

```
select StartDate
      ,EndDate
      ,datediff(day,StartDate,EndDate) as DayBoundariesCrossed
from YourTable
```

You will note that I have called that column `DayBoundariesCrossed` as that is what the `datediff` function actually returns.  By specifying the `day` as our `datepart` we get the number of times you cross from one day into the next between those two dates.  Had we specified `year` it would have been the number of year boundaries crossed.

This produces a potential pitfall called the fence post problem, where the value returned is likely one less than what you actually want; the `datediff` between today and tomorrow for example is just the one `day` boundary, though you may want to regard that as covering two days.  In those instances you can just add 1 to the result of the `datediff`.

A slightly more challenging consequence of this requires that you always use the most appropriate `datepart` for your calculations, as the results of 'boundaries crossed' are not always desirable.

For example, this script:

```
select datediff(year,'2020-12-31 23:59:59','2021-01-01 00:00:00') as YearBoundaries
      ,datediff(month,'2020-12-31 23:59:59','2021-01-01 00:00:00') as MonthBoundaries
      ,datediff(day,'2020-12-31 23:59:59','2021-01-01 00:00:00') as DayBoundaries
      ,datediff(hour,'2020-12-31 23:59:59','2021-01-01 00:00:00') as HourBoundaries
      ,datediff(minute,'2020-12-31 23:59:59','2021-01-01 00:00:00') as MinuteBoundaries
      ,datediff(second,'2020-12-31 23:59:59','2021-01-01 00:00:00') as SecondBoundaries
```

will output the following, which likely isn't what was desired:

| YearBoundaries | MonthBoundaries | DayBoundaries | HourBoundaries | MinuteBoundaries | SecondBoundaries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

To combat this, you can specify the `datepart` at a level of detail higher than what you are actually after and divide down - e.g. `datediff(month,StartDate,EndDate) / 12.0` to get year fractions - though even here there can be pitfalls that you will need to be mindful of.